# How do I customize my PowerShell prompt (colour and text)?

Tags: powershell, prompt

I'm running PowerShell 7.0.0 on Windows 10, and would like to customize my command prompt so it looks like the following:

`Username@Hostname YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS:PresentWorkingDirectory>`

with the following colors:

`username`: green

`hostname`: blue

`YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS`: purple

`:`: white

`PresentWorkingDirectory`: blue

`>`: white

## Question:

What is the requisite profile code to make the above happen? So far I know that `Get-Date -UFormat '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'` returns the `YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS` I want

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please show your code and tell us where exactly you get sutck or what does not work as expected? Have you tried to search before asking here?

Comment: @Olaf I literally said what I tried in my OP ... and at the time of writing this I didn't know my profile file location

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it:

```
function prompt {
    Write-Host $env:USERNAME -ForegroundColor Green -NoNewline
    Write-Host "@" -NoNewline
    Write-Host $env:COMPUTERNAME -ForegroundColor Blue -NoNewline
    Write-Host " $((Get-Date).toString('yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss'))" -ForegroundColor DarkMagenta -NoNewline 
    Write-Host ":" -NoNewline
    Write-Host $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation) -ForegroundColor Blue -NoNewline 
    "$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) "
}
```

I hope you have enough screens to span your terminal over it ;-)

[Learn more about PowerShell prompt customization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_prompts?view=powershell-7)

Comment: @Thomas Minimum display width is 1920 pixels on this end, so prompt length isn't a problem. In fact, thanks to high resolution displays it's not necessary for many things to be compact as it once was. Since I manage different machines across different OSes it's important for me to always exactly which machine and folder I'm working in any given time. Time and date help because if I leave the terminal open and return I can easily see when the last command I issued was. It's like having IM timestamps without having to run `history`.

Comment: @jdrch If you want to go really fancy with it you may follow this guy here: [Basic To Boss: Customizing Your PowerShell Prompt by Thomas Rayner](https://youtu.be/SdQYooRg7Cw)  ;-)